# Why do values lists retain filters in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, python-3.5

Given the Model class below:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
```

If I have a QuerySet of n Users, at least one of which has two friends, and retrieve the User by filtering that QuerySet by a friends id and perform a [.values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) call on that QuerySet, like this:

```
all_users = User.objects.all()
single_user = User.objects.filter(friends=2)
single_user.values_list('friends', flat=True)
```

Results in output like so:

```
>>> [2]
```

But if I perform that same .values_list call on the object's friends field itself, like this:

```
single_user.first().friends.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Results in an output of:

```
>>> [2, 3]
```

If these calls are being made on the same object, why is the output different?

For reference, this is achieved using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5.2

**EDIT**: I want to clear up some confusion. My issue is not that I misunderstand the results of the queries themselves. In both cases, I end up with the correct User object. The difference is in one case, I get a QuerySet of count 1 and in the other I get the instance of the User object.

So to state my question in a different manner: What I'm confused on is how does calling values_list on the different representations of the **same** object result in a different output?

Example, I have the following QuerySet

```
<QuerySet [<User: John Doe, ID: 1]>
```

And the following object, each in their own variables

```
<User: John Doe, ID: 1>
```

If I perform a values_list on the same field, in the necessary ways, I get two different results. I would like an explanation as to why. To me, I feel the results should be the same. Since they are not, I have a misunderstanding of how these things operate and am looking for clarification.

Comment: Users. Fixed the typos

Comment: It's an example to explain a point. This question is not about what models should be named, but about querysets. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I chose the singular to hopefully illustrate that it is an iterable of one. In our actual code, we follow the guidelines you've detailed. Edited the question, mostly, to hopefully improve readability.

Comment: This question was initially sparked because of the following query: `User.objects.filter(friends=2).values_list('friends', flat=True)`.  I feel this is important to state as it clears up a lot of the confusion as to how he got differing results.  The problem is not in that the values list was giving two different results on the same object but that the values_list was being chained directly with the filter.  The question in the title is in relation to this occurrence, not the examples displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a ManyToMany relationship, you get a new table to store relationships between two tables.

## yourapplabel_user_friends example

```
id | from_user_id | to_user_id |
1    1              2  
2    2              1
3    1              1
4    3              1
```

## User.objects.filter(friends=2)

```
User.objects.filter(friends=2)
# return : 1 instances because there are only one 2 in to_user_id column
User.objects.filter(friends=1)
# return : 3 instances
User.objects.filter(friends=3)
# return : 0 instances

single_user.filter(friends=2).values_list('friends', flat=True)
# return : [2]
single_user.filter(friends=2).values_list('id', flat=True)
# return : [1] 
#because id 1 User instance has friends which is id 2 as ManyToMany relationship

# this row
id | from_user_id | to_user_id |      
1    1              2
```

## single_user.objects.first()

```
single_user.objects.first()     
# single_user.objects.first() return first instance in user table. id 1 instance

single_user.objects.first().friends.values_list('id', flat=True)
# return : [2,1]
# id 1 instance has 2 instances in ManytoMany relationship.
# so it returns [2,1]

single_user.objects.last().friends.values_list('id', flat=True)
# return : [1]
# single_user.objects.last() returns id 3
# because I have 1,2,3 instances in User table as example.
# if you see yourapplabel_user_friends table, 3 id instance have 1 id as friends.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my situation, the single user object has two friends in the ManyToManyField. However, when I call values_list on the field of an instance (in this case, friends) and when I call values_list on a QuerySet containing that instance, it gives me two different results. If the field I'm trying to get the data for is the same, why do they act differently? Your answer uses the .objects of a Model class. I am working with QuerySets after already having filtered. I hope that clarifies. Sorry for long winded comment.

Comment: I want to check if you understand my answer fully first. I thought you couldn't understand difference between `single_user.objects.filter(friends=2).values_list('friends', flat=True)` and `single_user.objects.first().friends.values_list('id', flat=True)`. I gave you example data and example return to make you understand.

Comment: you defined manytomanyfield with 'self'. you can think from_user_id is user and to_user_id is friends. It could be confused because it refers to itself as 'self' manytomanyfield definition.

Comment: I fully understand the difference between the queries and the state of data on the two different lines. However, if you have an instance of the object: `user = User.objects.all().first()` and do `user.friends.values_list('id', flat=True)` it is performing the values_list on the QuerySet returned from the M2M manager. Which should yield the same results as `users = User.objects.filter(id=1)` and then doing `users.values_list('friends', flat=True)`. As I understand it, both are accessing the same field and the same table.

Comment: Okay. you understood `User.objects.filter(friends=something)` is different. Now, you changed it as `User.objects.filter(id=1)`. `User.objects.first().friends.values_list('id', flat=True)` and `User.objects.filter(id=1).values_list('friends', flat=True)` should return same result, i think. Can you share return for `User.objects.filter(id=1)`. `User.objects.first().friends.values_list('id', flat=True)` and `User.objects.filter(id=1).values_list('friends', flat=True)`

Comment: The code in the question is example code. I don't have outputs to copy paste to show directly. How is filtering by the friends field and the id field any different if I know for certain they will return the same object instance. Wherein my problem lies. My issue is not with my queries. I know they work. My issue is that I get a different result when calling values_list on a QuerySet vs on an Instance. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151010/discussion-between-jayground-and-neelik).

Answer (score 1):

They're different because the **two queries dont mean the same thing**!

`user.values_list('friends', flat=True)`  ...returns the ID's of friends of **user**

`user.first().friends.values_list('id', flat=True)`   ...returns the ID's of  friends of the **first friend of 'user'**.  In other words, you're actually looking up the friends of a *different* user here.

---

One good way of debugging things like these, is to **look at the SQL generated from a query.**   That may help you understand how Django is translating your query.

```
str(user.first().friends.values_list('id', flat=True).query)
```

vs.

```
str(user.values_list('friends', flat=True).query)
```

Can't read the output?  Use **sqlparse**!

```
sqlparse.format(str(user.first().friends.values_list('id', flat=True).query))
```

Comment: wouldn't user.first().friends.values_list() return a list of ids for the friends of the first user in the user QuerySet? In my case, both versions are acting on a single instance: One in a QuerySet and one as a Users Instance.

Comment: While it's true that two rather different SQL queries are generated by the QuerySets, I don't think @david-lam's interpretation of them is quite correct. The difference seems to indeed be whether one acts on a Model instance or an intermediate QuerySet.

Comment: @das-g Any idea why the results are different between Instance and QuerySet?

Comment: Well, because of the (somewhat naïve) way that Django builds the queries. Though whether the resulting Query from the QuerySet is the intended one (or rather, one calculating the intended result, despite that result being not-so-obvious) or whether that's a Django bug and the results of the Queries should actually be the same, I don't know.